# How do I change the colour of the mouseover correction suggestions in Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5

I have a big usability problem. The suggestions come up with a black background and mostly dark blue writing so it's really really hard to read. I can't find anything in Window-> Preferences -> Appearance that specifically mentions the correction suggestions. I've toyed around with the Ubuntu 'Appearance' settings but none of it seems to affect this. Also, anything that I do attempt to change in the appearances is not changed and has reverted back when I go back into the settings. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Galileo 3.5.2 32 bit with Android development tools running on Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after a couple of hours frustration but only minutes after asking this, I found that it was the Gnome window appearance settings after all! The setting can be found in 
System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Colours.
The Lucid Ubuntu default theme is apparently just bad for Eclipse...